# How to create and setup ONVIF PresetTour using onvif ver20 ptz.wsdl

Tags: c#, wsdl, onvif

I would like to know how to create and setup a PresetTour using the ONVIF standard.

Using the the [ONVIF ptz wsdl](https://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl) that has been added to my c# project's `Connected Services`, I can see that I can create a `PresetTour` for my `PTZClient`.

```
_ptzClient.CreatePresetTour(_profile.token);
```

After using this command, I can get the infos of this newly created preset tour using:

```
PresetTour[] tours = _ptzClient.GetPresetTours(_profile.token);
```

I would like to know how to create a new `TourSpot` or use an already existing `Preset` as a `TourSpot` to make my camera go to this spot when launching/starting the preset tour/patrol on my camera.

How do I set the position of a newly created tour spot?

How am I supposed to configure an entire `PresetTour`?

If there is no solution to my problem, I think I'll keep a list of preset on the side of my application and do everything manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `ModifyPresetTour`. It requires a `tt:PresetTour` struct, which has, among other fields, a `TourSpot` element of type `tt:PTZPresetTourSpot`. Beware that `TourSpot` is defined in the XML schema as `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"`, thus you can specify any number of tour spots.

The `PTZPresetTourSpot` struct has a `PresetDetail` filed of type `tt: PTZPresetTourPresetDetail`.

Finally `PTZPresetTourPresetDetail` has a `PresetToken` field, where you can specify the preset.

I agree it is not very *programmer-friendly*.